# Smart cover for smartphone with built-in spot for hosting headsets

Tags: smartphones, android, headphones

I am running Android 12 on a Realme 8 5G phone.

On the top of the back of my phone, to the left when my phone is facing up, there are four camera lenses.

I was wondering whether it would be possible at the back to also host a space for headphones, given that my fingers (index finger, of course), never reaches there.

That way, headphones would be part of the phone, and not be left behind.

Comment: What do you mean by "hosting"? A place to store the headphones?

Comment: You can't alter the phone physically.  Are you asking for a recommendation  for a phone with a audio jack ?